# How to grab the names of all sub-folders in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I just want to know how can I get all the names of the folders in a current directory. For example in my current directory I have three folders:

```
stackoverflow
reddit
codinghorror
```

Then when I execute my batch script all the three folders will print in the screen.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using batch files:

```
for /d %%d in (*.*) do echo %%d
```

If you want to test that on the command line, use only one % sign in both cases.

Comment: "for /d %%d in (*.*) do @echo %%d" is prettier.

Comment: You mean `for /d %%d in (*) do @echo %%d`?

Comment: @Helen: yes, the asteriskes apparently were swallowed.

Comment: They caused an italic dot :-) You have to enclose your code in \` :-)

Answer (score 8):

On Windows, you can use:

```
dir /ad /b
```

`/ad` will get you the directories only
`/b` will present it in 'bare' format

EDIT (reply to comment):

If you want to iterate over these directories and do something with them, use a `for` command:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b') do (
   echo %%a
)
```

- note the double `%` - this is for use in a batch, if you use for on the command line, use a single `%`.
- added the resetting of default space delims in response to @Helen's comment

Comment: You forgot "delims=" to deal with folders that have spaces in their names.

Answer (score 2):

With PowerShell:

```
gci | ? { $_.PSIsContainer }
```

---

Old Answer:

With PowerShell:

```
gci | ? {$_.Length -eq $null } | % { $_.Name }
```

You can use the result as an array in a script, and then foreach trough it, or whatever you want to do...

Comment: Or you can filter using {$_.Mode -like "d*" } instead of the Length thing. I'm sure that a PowerShell guru will read this and show us the right solution.

Comment: `gci | ?{$_.PSIsContainer}` is the canonical way, actually.

Comment: Also, please don't reduce objects to string unless you absolutely have to. This causes more harm than good in most cases.

Comment: Good point, though the output described by sasayins was to have only directory names.

Answer (score 0):

For getting all the subfolders of a specific directory and display it in CMD :

```
@echo off
dir C:\input /s /b /o:n /a:d
Pause&Exit
```

For getting all the subfolders of a specific directory and save it in a text file :

```
dir C:\your_directory /s /b /o:n /a:d > output.txt
```