# Windows batch file - display all sub-folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, subdirectory

I'm having difficulty returning JUST folders (ignore files) using a windows batch file.

Here's what I have right now. Currently it's returing files and sub-sub-folders.

```
for /r %%g in ("xx*") do echo %%g
```

Also, say I want to only return the folders that start with a couple different prefixes.

For example: I want to echo only the folders that start with w*, we*, cm*, cr*, etc under within in the folder "work". I do  Is this possible using a batch file?

Thanks.

Comment: for /d %%d in (*.*) do echo %%d http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487214/how-to-grab-the-names-of-all-sub-folders-in-a-batch-script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `dir` command with the modifier `/a:d` which will tell it to only search directories

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('DIR /a:d /b w*') DO (
    ECHO %%i
)
```

This will find all of the subfolders that start with `w*`

Comment: Thanks andrew, do you know if you can search for all of those prefixes at once by chance?

Comment: I don't know of a way to search for multiple prefixes at once without a more complicated IF statement (something like list everything, then check everything to see if it matches the pattern).

Answer (score 3):

Here's modified version of Andrew's answer that can handle multiple prefixes:

```
dir /a:d /b w* we* cm* cr*
```