# Batch Script to Find a Folder inside Sub Folders and get Path

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I'm trying to get path of a directory containing **.snapshot** folder. .snapshot should be searched in all parent and sub-directories.

I've a directory structure resembling following tree command output (only more complex, deployment deals a huge NAS drive)

[image]

My script, as below, so far lists only one out of potentially 100s of directories containing .snapshot

```
set Dir=C:\Vol
cd %Dir%
for /d  /r "%Dir%" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"==".snapshot" set "folderpath=%%a"
echo "%folderpath%"
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Vol\xnd76540\u44753\mike.smith\.snapshot
```

My Question

How can I check all sub-directories of a folder for .snapshot, come back to the parent and follow another path for again searching .snapshot in other set of sub directories and so on?
Performance tips appreciated.

Couldn't find a more relevant code snippet.

Comment: Can you use any other scripting language such as python, php etc?

Comment: Toby Allen, Unfortunately a big NO. Client rejected even VBScript & PowerShell.

Comment: if you modify the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664929/windows-batch-file-display-all-sub-folders you should be able to get all subfolders called .snapshot (it just took a google search)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it almost done

```dos
for /d  /r "%Dir%" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"==".snapshot" (
    echo %%~dpa
)
```

Or,

```dos
for /d /r "%Dir%" %%a in (.snapshot) do if exist "%%~fa" (
    echo %%~dpa
)
```

The problem with the original `for` in the question is that it is assigning a variable while iterating, and when the `for` ends, the value echoed is the last assigned as in each iteration the value is overwritten.

Instead, echoing the value inside the running `for` you will have the full list.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks MC ND.  Any performance tips you are aware of in current situation? It will run on a nas drive with potentially several hundred Tera Bytes of data.

Comment: @AbdullahLeghari, your problem is not how many data there is in the drive, but the number of folders to process. You can use any variation on the previous code, or a `for /f` processing a `dir` output, or, ... but in any case you will have to iterate the folder structure. Unless you know that the `.snapshot` folder will always be in a precise deep level so you can cut the recursion, there are not much options.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
set Dir=%1
cd %Dir%
for /d  /r "%Dir%" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"==".snapshot" set "folderpath=%%a"
echo "%folderpath%"
```

Save this Batch file say temp.bat

Now in another batch file call it by passing arguments like

```
temp.bat "C:\Vol1"
temp.bat "another location"
```

Comment: Thanks Amit for answer. Going through it

Comment: Make sure you pass the argument in double quotes (to avoid a situation where directory path might contain white space)

Comment: This code also returns the *last* item only, like the snippet from the original question; so you need to include the `echo` within the body of `for`, or you simply skip the assignment of the interim variable `folderpath` and just put `echo "%%~fa"` instead of the `set` command (the `~f` modifier returns the *full* path without enclosing quotes); and the `cd` command before `for` should be omitted to avoid trouble with relative path arguments...

Comment: If you want to find just the first occurrence instead of the last occurrence, use: `set "folderpath=" & 
for /d  /r "%Dir%" %%a in (*) do if not defined folderpath if /i "%%~nxa"==".snapshot" set "folderpath=%%a"`